# Forcing Micro:Bit Shutdown

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

I have this code for a parking system. When the number of spaces goes above 20 it sends and error message due to 20 being the limit of spaces. I want to try shutdown the program after this point.

I have tried doing what you can do in Python. This is:

```
import sys
display.scroll("Error: Limit exceeded.")
sys.exit()
```

This gives me an attribute error.

```
from microbit import *
import sys

elif spaces > 20:

        display.scroll("Error: The spaces have exceeded the limit.")
        sys.exit()
```

This should shutdown the program, not letting it to function, after the elif statement. There is more code (if statements, loops, function) but it is irrelevant.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why? As in, what is the purpose of shutting down?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple ways I can think of.

In general, you can just enter an infinite loop, which will effectively halt everything, if there's no way to interrupt the loop:

```py
while True:
    microbit.sleep(1000000)  # wait for 1000 seconds until the end of time
```

In micro:bit's documentation there's also [`microbit.panic()`](https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/microbit.html#microbit.panic), which, quote, "requires a restart" of the micro:bit:

```py
microbit.panic(0)
```

You could see if that works for you.

And since the micro:bit uses MicroPython as its Python implementation, you can look [here](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/quickref.html#general-board-control) in the MicroPython documentation:

```py
import pyb

pyb.stop() # stop CPU, waiting for external interrupt
```

However, if an external interrupt does occur (and one might), the program would then probably continue.

Comment: `import pyb` is pyboard only code. It's only available in the pyboard version of micropython not in microbit

Comment: @rhubarbdog Good to know. Glad I didn't suggest it as my first alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is a bit misleading as it must be in a `while True:` loop. Just breakout of that outer loop.